# Negative margin clips the image in react native app in Android

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, flexbox

I am making a react native app [in which one of my screen is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aezrz.png) I am trying to make the profile overlap on background image but when I give negative margin that is marginTop: -40 . It clips the profile image .  Profile image does not overlap on background image and I am new to react native so can anyone tell me how to fix this thing

here is my code

```
<Container style={{ backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF', }}>




                <Content>



                    <Image source={{ uri: 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/reactnativechatapp-6f7eb.appspot.com/o/Ontro%20Copy%209.png?alt=media&token=2ede2451-0a14-4988-a9e2-ba88bab2c844' }}
                        style={styles.image}>

                    </Image>

                    <View style={{
                        flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'flex-start',
                        justifyContent: 'space-between', marginLeft: 10,
                        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF', flex: 1,  marginRight: 15,
                    }}>


                        <View style={{
                            flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'flex-start',position:'relative',
                            justifyContent: 'flex-start', zIndex:-20,marginTop:-40, borderRadius: 33,
                            borderStyle: 'solid',
                            borderWidth: 3,
                            borderColor: '#F0F0F0'

                        }}>
                            <Thumbnail style={{
                                borderRadius: 30,
                                height: 60,
                                width: 60

                            }} source={{ uri: 'https://placeimg.com/640/480/people' }} />

                        </View>


                        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column', marginBottom: 15 }}>
                            <Text style={{ color: '#9F2232', fontSize: 22, }}>Cecelia Fletcher</Text>


                            <Text style={{ color: '#9E9C9E', fontSize: 12, }}>West Mambalam</Text>
                        </View>

                        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', marginTop: 5 }}>
                            <Icon style={{ color: '#AE6772', flex: 0 }} name="md-checkmark-circle" />
                            <Text style={{ color: '#9F2232', fontSize: 14, marginLeft: 6, marginTop: 3 }}>Joined</Text>
                            <Icon style={{ color: '#AE6772', flex: 0, marginLeft: 5 }} name="md-arrow-dropdown" />
                        </View>

                        <Icon name="md-more" />
                    </View>

 image: {
        flexGrow: 1,
        height: 250,
        width: null,

    },
```

Answer (score -1):

Not to use negative margin instead use position:'absolute'